# Electron - fs.js:114 Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open

Tags: node.js, electron

I have a simple application with an `export` button. When this button is clicked, open a popup to add more data and create a pdf with `JsPDF`.
When I click on the `export` button the popup appears correctly but clicking on the`finish` button (to close it), this error appears on the console:

```
fs.js:114 Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
at Object.openSync (fs.js:436)
at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as openSync] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:160:31)
at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:341)
at Object.fs.readFileSync (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:580)
at Object.exports.base64Sync (/Users/th3g3ntl3man/Repository/thermowell-design/node_modules/base64-img/base64-img.js:60)
at HTMLButtonElement.$.on (export.min.js:1)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
at HTMLDocument.y.handle (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
```

This is a small code linked with the `export` button:

```
const JsPDF   = require('jspdf');

let customer, project, tag;
var pdf = new JsPDF();


$(document).ready( () => {

    $(document).on("click","#additionalData", () => {

        customer = $('#customer').val().trim();
        tag = $('#tag').val().trim();
        pN = $('#pN').val().trim();

        pdf.text(50, 50, 'this is a test');

        pdf.save(customer + '_' + tag + '.pdf');
        $("#custom-modal").modal("hide");
    });


    $('#esporta').click( () => {
        $("#custom-modal").modal("show");
    });

});
```

`additionalData` is the form for insert the new data and `custom-modal` is the popup.

Comment: As I show the document of JsPDF it shows me that you need to write `pdf.text('this is a test', 50, 50) `.

Comment: @utsav When you click on the `finish` button of the popup, it's open a windows for saving the file (choose the name of the file and the path where save these)